# Laravel Nova tool is not showing anything

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a admin panel using Laravel Nova. I am creating a tool which is the new feature of Nova, https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/tools.html#overview. I am having a problem using it. See what I have done so far.

I run this command,

```
php artisan nova:tool {tool-name}
```

Then I register it in the NovaServiceProvider.

Then I run

```
npm run dev
```

The tool is added to the sidebar. But when I click on it, it is showing nothing. in the console, this is the error I got.

[image]

The documentation is not telling anything how to go further as well. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not compile the frontend assets. Run `npm run prod` to compile them and see if the error persists.